# "exit" event is thrown after board is "ready"

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi2, angular-fullstack, johnny-five

I'm trying to control 3 leds plugged into my raspberry-pi2, and I installed johnny-five to do that.
I don't think it is linked to the problem, but there were a slight error while installing johnny-five, described at the end of the post.

I have a simple code generated by angular-fullstack, which works **before enabling johnny-five** (I can press buttons to call server-side, I get answer on client-side and everything is fine)

Then I add johnny-five like this ():

```
'use strict'

var Raspi = require("raspi-io");
var five = require("johnny-five");
var raspi_io = new Raspi();
var board = new five.Board({
 io: raspi_io // if I comment this line, server won't stop, but then I can't access my led, which is the goal of raspi-io...
});

board.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Board ready !");
});
```

And I get these logs when I run `sudo grunt serve`:

> Board ready !
>   Express server listening on 9000, in development mode
>   KO: (debug log) exit signal detected in repl.js (johnny-five)
>   1469358904063 **Board Closing**.
>   Stopping Express server
>   Done waiting!

Then, I can see the board "ready" event has been triggered, so it looks fine. But then, the board closes, and so does the server, and I can't understand why. I added as many log as I could, but couldn't see where the "exit" event is triggered. I'm stuck here (in repl.js from johnny-five):

```
  this.cmd = cmd;
  this.context = cmd.context;

  cmd.on("exit", function() {
    // this is the triggered event, can't find where the cmd.exit is triggered...
    state.board.emit("exit");
    state.board.warn("Board", "Closing.");
    process.nextTick(process.reallyExit);
  });
```

Also, I noticed that "blink" doesn't work on leds (if I use them in the ready function), whatever params I set...

### Version & Installations :

> npm -v
>   3.8.6
>   nodejs -v
>   5.11.1

and installed johnny-five this way:

> sudo npm install johnny-five raspi-io --save
>   npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
>   npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture:   fsevents@1.0.14
>   npm WARN karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.0 requires a peer of phantomjs-prebuilt@>=1.9 but none was installed.

when I try to install fsevents (or phantomjs-prebuilt):

> sudo npm install fsevents --save
>   npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
>   npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
>   npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
>   npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
>   npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: arm

### Question:

Does anyone have a clue why the server stops ?

Comment: Maybe the "board" object gets killed somehow, which would explain the "exit" event, but there is no reason for that... (or maybe I'm missing something...)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this problem, give a try with:

```
 const board = new five.Board({
        repl: false,
        port: 'COM3'
    });
```